# Group and count entries in a DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I'm new to programming and Pandas, I'd like to have an example of how to apply a grouping function that also applies some counters to reduce the following DataFrame:

| child | groupName | state |
| --- | --- | --- |
| name1 | A | ok |
| name2 | A | ko |
| name3 | B | ok |

to a new DataFrame like:

| groupName | noOfChildren | noOfOk | noOfKo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| B | 1 | 1 | 0 |

Given the allChildren DataFrame, I can create the Series counting the entries by groupName:

```
childrenByGroupName= allChildren.groupby(['groupName'])['name'].count();
```

And also the Series to filter them by 'ok' state:

```
okChildrenByGroupName= allChildren.where(['state']=='ok').groupby(['groupName'])['name'].count();
```

But I cannot build the merged DataFrame as per the above expectation.
Any help?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
pd.crosstab(df['groupName'], df['state'], margins='sum')
```

Output:

```
state      ko  ok  All
groupName             
A           1   1    2
B           0   1    1
All         1   2    3
```

and to (almost) match the expected output:

```
(pd.crosstab(df['groupName'], df['state'], margins='sum', margins_name='Children')
   .drop('Children')
   .add_prefix('noOf')
   .reset_index()
)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try like this:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['groupName']).agg({'child': 'count', 'state': lambda x: x.value_counts().to_dict()}).add_prefix('noOf').reset_index()
df2 = pd.concat([df1.drop('noOfstate', axis=1), pd.DataFrame(df1['noOfstate'].tolist()).add_prefix('noOf')], axis=1).fillna(0)
```

**df2:**

```
    groupName   noOfchild   noOfok  noOfko
0   A           2           1       1.0
1   B           1           1       0.0
```